# Admin doesnt opening on OpenCart3

Tags: opencart

I have an issue with OC3:
When I open admin page i has only white page. When I open error log I have anything, all is okay but page doesnt open.
My config file:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://nanox.md/admin');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://nanox.md/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://nanox.md/admin');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://nanox.md/');


// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/bodybuilding/public_html/nanox/catalog/admin');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/bodybuilding/public_html/nanox/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/bodybuilding/public_html/nanox/image/');
define('DIR_STORAGE', DIR_SYSTEM . 'storage/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'language/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/bodybuilding/public_html/nanox/catalog/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', DIR_SYSTEM . 'config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', DIR_STORAGE . 'cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', DIR_STORAGE . 'logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', DIR_STORAGE . 'modification/');
define('DIR_SESSION', DIR_STORAGE . 'session/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'upload/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', '*');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '*');
define('DB_DATABASE', '*');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

And link to the admin page is http://nanox.md/admin

Please help :)

Comment: can you send msg on bhoraniyamujahid@gmail.com. i will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your admin folder is not on catalog folder so replace this:

```
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/bodybuilding/public_html/nanox/catalog/admin');
```

with this

```
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/bodybuilding/public_html/nanox/admin');
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have missed the last "/" in your Application definition, additionally, your path is incorrect, there is no `admin` folder in the catalog, try replacing this:

```
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/bodybuilding/public_html/nanox/catalog/admin');
```

with this:

```
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/bodybuilding/public_html/nanox/admin/');
```

Comment: What does your php error log say @CristianCiubuc